# modify html output when add image in posts and pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm trying to edit the output of add image in posts the normal code from wordpress is

```
<a href="http://huemix.ly/wp-content/pics/pic.jpg"><img src="http://huemix.ly/wp-content/pics/pic.jpg" /></a>
```

i want to replace that output with

```
<div class="huemix">
    <img class="posts-img" src="http://huemix.ly/wp-content/pics/pic.jpg" />
    <a href="http://huemix.ly/wp-content/pics/pic.jpg" class="fancybox" ></a>
    <div class="fancy"></div>
</div>
```

all my try goes down :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search proper chunk of code in wordpress functions file. The file should be named `post.php` and should be located in `wp-includes`. The function name should be `wp_insert_attachment()`.

Or using filters:

```
<?php 
       add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'my_image_func', 10, 7);
       function my_image_func($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $url, $size ) {
           $url = wp_get_attachment_url($id); // Grab the current image URL
           $html = "<img src="$url" class="uhuhu"/>";
           return $html;
       }
?>
```